# LibreOffice file-save strategy : why?

Tags: libreoffice, inotify

This is the `inotifywait` output during a File.Save action on `400.Oliver.odt`. The watch is on the directory.

```
./ CREATE lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ OPEN lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ OPEN lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ MODIFY lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ ACCESS lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ MODIFY lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ MODIFY lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ ACCESS lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ MODIFY lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ MOVED_FROM lu35285h45cvw.tmp
./ MOVED_TO 400.Oliver.odt
./ ATTRIB 400.Oliver.odt
./ ATTRIB 400.Oliver.odt
./ OPEN 400.Oliver.odt
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 400.Oliver.odt
./ OPEN 400.Oliver.odt
./ OPEN 400.Oliver.odt
./ ACCESS 400.Oliver.odt
./ ACCESS 400.Oliver.odt
./ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE 400.Oliver.odt
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 400.Oliver.odt
```

What programming principle / practice motivates the use of the temporary file?

`lu35285h45cvm.tmp` is CREATEd for each save, then presumably data from the session is written to the temporary file then the temporary file is closed and moved to the odt file.

Why not simply write the data to the odt file? I'm sure there's a good reason, I'm not questioning that. But I'm interested in why?

Comment: You need to read the source to make sure. (Open Source Software is a wonderful thing, isn't it?) Presumably they try use the same method for saving a new file and to save in an existing file. To ensure that writing all the file's contents before the original is removed, that temporary file is used. Only after success, the original will be removed and the temporary renamed. Would you mind to record that variant, too?

Comment: @thebusybee That's a good reason indeed. Nice. What do you mean with your last question?

Comment: Record the file accesses during a save to an existing file, like after initially have saved it, make some changes, and save it again. Or, saving over an existing file.